# Character deletion from a string in java

Tags: java, string

I have a string `*dfgi*kjklx`  . I want to delete the character before and after *  the output should be

```
fgjklx
```

I have written my code like this but it shows me index out of bound error.

```
String t = "*dfgi*kjklx";
 for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
  {
   String temp = s.charAt(i);
   if(temp == ‘*’)
    {
      t = t.replace(s.charAt(i), '');
      t = t.replace(s.charAt(i-1), '');
      t = t.replace(s.charAt(i+1), '');
      System.out.println("String: " + t);
     }
  }
```

Comment: This code cannot compile. Could you post your real code?

Comment: 1.  That code won't compile.  Show us the real code.  2. Show us the stack trace.

Comment: You need to check the `i-1` and `i+1` don't leave your boundaries, E.G.
`if (i-1 >= 0) t = t.replace(s.charAt(i-1), ''); if(i+1 <s.length()) t = t.replace(s.charAt(i+1), '');`

Or use the regex to simplify it further as TheLostMind has done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might approach this with a `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(t.length());
for (int i = 0; i < t.length(); ++i) {
  if (t.charAt(i) != '*'                     // Check the current character.
      && (i == 0 || t.charAt(i - 1) != '*')  // Check the prev character.
      && (i + 1 >= t.length() || t.charAt(i + 1) != '*')) {  // Check the next.
    sb.append(t.charAt(i));
  }
}
t = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use a regex like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String s = "*dfgi*kjklx";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\w?\\*\\w?", "")); // replace 0 or 1 [a-zA-Z0-9] * 0 or 1 [a-zA-Z0-9].
}
```

O/P :

> fgjklx

Edit : Like Andy says in his comment, you can use `.` instead of `\\w` to remove "anything" that is followed by or preceeded by a "*".

Comment: I'd just go for `.` instead of `\w`: the question just says "character", not any particular character class.